# Should I update my address tied to an old bank account if I'm planning to move again in a couple of months?

Tags: united-kingdom, credit-score, bank-account

I have just realised an old bank account of mine (overdrawn, making irregular payments to counter the interest while I focus on higher priority debts) still has my old address.

It's been three years since I lived at that address, but I will be moving again in a month or two. I'm not sure which of the following options is best, as far as my credit score is concerned:

1. Tell the bank about my current address now, then tell them of my
   new address when I move
2. Wait until I move, then just give them my new address

Other bank accounts, cards, electoral register are up to date.

I'm worried that #1 could be seen as unreliable behaviour - Changing address twice in two months hardly seems like a mark of stability

I'm worried that #2 will then leave a permanent discrepancy between the sources for my address history, which could be interpreted as dishonest, fraudulent or just generally irresponsible.

What should I do for the best?

Comment: Did you have other credits(bank accounts, credit cards) also at the old address which have been updated with the new address ? Means they existed at the old address and were updated with the new address when you moved.

Comment: Yeah, several other accounts or official records show my complete address history. My official address history attached to my credit report (ie, not attributed to a single source) is also correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The damage has already been done. Your address discrepancy willn't matter much as you have other credits which have your new addresses and are connected to your old address.  So you addresses will have already been linked, without any breaks, to identify you as the same person.

> overdrawn, making irregular payments to counter the interest while I focus on higher priority debts

The bank might have tried contacting you for payments, any letters or visits you received or know of. They might have tried to help you in your payments, you might have missed the chance. Many banks tend to have schemes to help people in difficulty. So don't do that again and check your balance left in the account. They might have added fees. Never do that again, and always keep your bank in loop as they might be able to help. Contact the bank and explain your scenario, it is never too late.

And check if they haven't sent it across to any debt collection agency, which is a very unhelpful scenario. If bailiffs turn up, which isn't pleasant, be prepared. There are some scum bailiffs who try to scam you money, against the law. Get some help in how to deal with them. Ask the citizen's advice for help, if it comes to that.

> 1.Tell the bank about my current address now, then tell them of my new address when I move

Tell them now about your current address and when you move update them immediately. It doesn't matter much in how frequently you change because you real staying time in an address isn't only collated from one credit, but all credits you have.

> 2.Wait until I move, then just give them my new address

This also mightn't be a bad option. Change and then update them. Or call up the bank and ask for advice.

But get in touch with the bank. Bailiff's at your door is never ever good. Those idiots turn up at odd times, to catch you at your most vulnerable moment.